# How can I cut off a array in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to delete n percentage of beginning and m percentage of ending of my array but I don't know how to do it. Would you please help?

Comment: `a=a(5:end-6)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume we're dealing with a **vector** `A` of 80 elements:

```
A = 1:80;
N = numel(A);
n = 0.1; m = 0.15;
```

If we only want to remove a certain number (or percentage) of elements from the beginning and the end we can take several approaches:

- **Indexing a subset** (what [Ander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485872/ander-biguri) suggested):

  ```
  A1 = A(round(n*N):end-round(m*N));
  ```

  where [`end`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85564) designates the last element in a particular dimension of an array.
- **Deleting elements by assigning `[]`**:

  ```
  A1 = A; A1(1:round(n*N)-1) = []; A1(end-round(m*N)+1:end) = [];
  ```

In some cases you want to delete elements not according to their position in the vector, but according to their value (or percentile), in which case you would do:

```
p = prctile(A(:),[n m]*100);   % Returns percentiles p of a data set.
A1 = A(A >= p(1) & A <= p(2));
```

Comment: @Paris You're welcome. However, you can see that your question got some negative votes - this is a sign that it should be improved. I would suggest editing it and adding a demonstration of what you want to do, because my answer is based on a _guess_, and just happened to be helpful... Take a look at [ask] and [mcve].